# How to increase Stripe's API's risk_score to 99?

Tags: stripe-payments

Not sure if this is possible. Tried looking into the docs

[https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-outcome-risk_score][1]

Answer (score 0):

Stripe provides 3 [test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) that lead to high levels of risk for testing your Radar rules and anti-fraud checks:

- `4000000000009235`   Results in a charge with a risk_level of elevated.
- `4000000000004954`   Results in a charge with a risk_level of highest.
- `4100000000000019`   Results in a charge with a risk_level of highest.
  The charge is blocked as it’s considered fraudulent.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if that's not sufficient you'll need to provide more detail to allow people to help you.

Comment: oh this isn't for testing, I wanna find out how to "jailbreak" Stripe's max UI risk limit of 90 to 99